# Use background-image AND center without gap for Outlook

Tags: css, outlook, html-email, vml

Since using background images in an HTML mail for outlook 2007-2016 is not supported by CSS I tried this workound with [VML](https://backgrounds.cm/):

This is my DOM before using VML:

```
<table width="100%" align="center" height="227" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
  <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#F4C046"   
           style="background-image: url('../image.jpg');
                  background-repeat: no-repeat;
                  background-size: cover; 
                  background-position: center;
                  background-color:#F4C046;border:solid">
      <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <!--- some content -->
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now this works for most email clients, but in outlook 2007-2016 the background-image is ignored and in renders without the background color like this:

[image]

When I try to use the "VML" solution my code looks like this:

```
<table width="100%" align="center" height="227" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
  <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#F4C046"   
           style="background-image: url('../image.jpg');
                  background-repeat: no-repeat;
                  background-size: cover; 
                  background-position: center;
                  background-color:#F4C046;border:solid">
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
     <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;">
        <v:fill type="frame" src="../myimg.jpg" color="#F4C046" />
            <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
            <![endif]-->    
      <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <!--- some content -->
      </table>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:textbox>
            </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now the background is working, hover the table thats on the background is not centered anymore:

[image]

Also if I make the outlook window small a gap appears:

[image]

I could wrap my table that should be centered one more time with a full with table like this:

```
<table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">   
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <!--- some content -->
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

to fix the centering:

[image]

However the gap still appears:

[image]

Any idea how to properly use background image and center the content, without the gap issue?

Comment: Try the `<center>` tag around the table.

Comment: @Tomalak thank you for your suggestion! I replaced the full width table with the `<center>` tag but unfortunatly nothing changes. Works on a wide window but the yellow gap still appears when shrinking the window.

Comment: Too bad. What happens if you style the `<v:textbox>` with `align: center;`?

Comment: @Tomalak if I change the code to `style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true;align:center"` it does not seem to align anything. However, I just noticed that the centering is not the cause of the gap. Once I add the "VML" the gap appears and the centering is ignored. So the gap is not caused by any of the center solutions I tried, but its caused by the "VML". I will edit this insight in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whats wrong with your code, but maybe you can use this I found in an old email I made. It works with outlook 2010,13,16. I hope it helps you.

NB: Dont mind all the classes :)

```
<table bgcolor="#efefef" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
            class="w394 w355-413 w300-374" width="640">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" background="https://placeimg.com/640/540/arch" bgcolor="#efefef"
                  class="w394 w355-413 w300-374 break h400" height="540"
                  style="background-size:640px 960px;repeat:no-repeat;" width="640">
                  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:640px;height:540px;">
                      <v:fill type="tile" src="https://placeimg.com/640/540/arch" color="#efefef" />
                      <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                      <![endif]-->
                  <div>
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td height="50">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                      class="w280 w240-413" valign="middle" width="320">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" class="f28"
                            style="padding:20px;font-size:36px;line-height:40px;font-family: Arial;font-weight: 400;color:#be1f24;"
                            valign="top">Lorem <b>IPSUM</b> dolor <b>sit </b>amet</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td height="50">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    </v:textbox>
                    </v:rect>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>    
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you I will tryit out now.

Comment: My litmus test shows everything correct.. well atleast the center table on bg part :)

Comment: So your template differs from mine because yours has a fixed width, while I use full width. If onr removes the width attribute from your sub-table and td, and removes the style from `<:rect` but add `style="mso-width-percent:1000;"` I get the same issue. Sometimes a gap appears when I change outlook window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxF4C.png